# Which user owns X display?

Tags: xorg, x11, users

How to determine, as root, which user owns X display :0? (on a Fedora 18 system with defaults)

**Clarification:** I want to know which user has original permissions to connect to :0 and grant other users permission to connect. Per current answers below, it seems that root owns the X process but the user who launched it may have permissions.

Comment: Is your question actually is "who opened a session on display :0?" ? If this is the case, you should consider edit your question. Here, I understand the question as "who launched the process that created the display :0?".

Comment: And if the question is "which user is is connected to display `:0`", there is no good answer: Multiple user can be connected to `:0`, and, with networking enabled on the X server, even users that don't exist on the local machine. Yes, today mostly a single user logs in to X, but that isn't how the architecture works.

Comment: @lgeorget no, that's not the question. I have added a clarification

Comment: @dirkt added a clarification to my question

Answer (score 3):

`ps -ef|grep X` will give you the info.

For example, on my computer:

```
user001  2721  2705  0 02:35 tty1     00:00:00 xinit /home/user001/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 -auth /home/user001/.serverauth.2705
root      2722  2721 13 02:35 tty7     00:10:10 /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp :0 -auth /home/user001/.serverauth.2705
user001  3475  3462  0 03:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep X
```

Here, we can see that `user001` launched `xinit` and uses the display `:0`. However, `root` is the owner of the `X` process.

On most installations, users don't use the `xinit` command (or `startx` which internally calls `xinit`). The X server is launched by root during the bootup process. In that case, root is the "owner" of the display.

Comment: no xinit shows up on my system, fedora 18 with defaults

Comment: Ok, but you see a `X` process owned by root? That means that the X server is launched and owned by root. So, you have your answer. I'll edit my answer to deal with that case.

Comment: hmm.. yes, but i did not login as root on the graphical user and the display is not owned by root. i think the "-auth /home/user0001/..." line might help though

Comment: If your question is "how to know who is logged in", try the `w` command. And please reformulate your question, it's a bit ambiguous ;-).

Answer (score 1):

[**loginctl**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) from systemd to the rescue:

```
loginctl --no-legend list-sessions \
  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 \
  | while read sessionid; do \
    [ $(loginctl --property Type --value show-session $sessionid) = 'x11' ] \
      && loginctl --property Name --value show-session $sessionid; \
  done
```

Get the list of session IDs, see which one is of type `x11` and print the user name. For Wayland the type is `wayland` and for MIR is `mir` according to the  [logind D-Bus API Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/).

Interactive use:

```
[ciupicri@titan /]$ loginctl list-sessions 
SESSION  UID USER     SEAT  TTY
      2 5000 ciupicri seat0    
      4 6000 somebody             
      9 6000 somebody             

3 sessions listed.
[ciupicri@titan /]$ loginctl show-session 2
Id=2
User=5000
Name=ciupicri
Timestamp=Thu 2019-09-12 16:24:12 EEST
TimestampMonotonic=46881112
VTNr=1
Seat=seat0
Display=:0
Remote=no
Service=lightdm-autologin
Desktop=xfce
Scope=session-2.scope
Leader=2072
Audit=2
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
LockedHint=no
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact command:

```
ps ho user $(pgrep X)
```

Comment: not tested but seems intelligent and in the right ballpark. upvoting to negate an uncommented downvote.

Comment: Does not work for me on a Debian system with Lightdm and Mate. The owner of the Xorg process is root, so the result is always root

Answer (score 0):

To answer your clarification: It depends.

It's possible for a user to start an X server.

However, most distros use a display manager (DM) to start the X server. This is a system service owned by root, which starts the X server as root, display a login screen, and then grant this particular user access to this display (e.g. `:0`) via `xauth`.

As to "which user can grant other users permissions to connect": Again, it depends. By default, modern distros use `xauth`, and restrict the X server to local user. Then, any user who is already connected can use `xauth` to obtain a valid MIT authorization cookie, and pass this cookie on to another user, with then in turn can connect after adding this cookie.

Unless the distro has taken additional measures to make sure only one user can connect the unix domain socket that corresponds to that display (I wouldn't be surprised if some distros do that).

Comment: I think Xorg would also listen on an abstract Unix domain socket, so anyone can connect to that socket? Although Xorg may refuse to give any further X11 protocol response, but connect() syscall will succeed for any user.

Answer (score 0):

One example that works on Ubuntu 18.04 with GDM (did not try lightdm).
So for this scenario it does answer that questions. Just if someone wants to delete the answer again.... (how to find users of a display).

For GDM on Ubuntu 18.04

```
loginctl show-session 2 -p Display
```

will print `Display=` although being the session using the display. The solutions below worked though.

---

```bsh
~$ who
user     :1           2020-03-02 07:28 (:1)
user     tty3         2020-03-03 09:39
user     pts/1        2020-03-03 10:19 (some IP)
```

or

```bsh
~$ w
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     tty7     :0               15:12    1:48m  1:50   0.23s /usr/lib/gnome-
user     pts/2    SomeIP           16:58    1:39   0.04s  0.04s -bash
```

As you said since the Xserver is started by the DM it will run as root or similar user (as it is allowed to access HW devices of the seat). To allow another session to use an authority file is created for the User.

---

Another solution I found on [Best way to identify logged-in users and their DISPLAY?](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?pid=36727#p36727) (but will fail as soon as multiple users run on the same X display I think) is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash


declare -A disps usrs
usrs=()
disps=()
for i in $(users);do
    [[ $i = root ]] && continue
    usrs[$i]=1
done # unique names

#Use .*DISPLAY=(\w*:[0-9.]+).* if you want to see DISPLAY of form :0.1 
#or localhost:10.0 too
for u in "${!usrs[@]}"; do
    for i in $(sudo ps e -u "$u" | sed -rn 's/.* DISPLAY=(:[0-9]*).*/\1/p');do
        disps[$i]=$u
    done
done

for d in "${!disps[@]}";do
    echo "User: ${disps[$d]}, Display: $d"
done
```

It basically queries the env of all processes of a user and saves for each  display which user did belong to it. (Did work for my VNC displays too).